# Pullback of box products of invertible sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $S, T$ be graded $A$-algebras (where $S_0 = A = T_0$) finitely generated in degree $1$ and let $M$ be a quasi-finitely generated graded $S$-module, $N$ a quasi-finitely generated graded $T$-module. Recall (Hartshorne, II, Exercise 5.9 (c)) that $M$ is said to be quasi-finitely generated if $M_{\ge d} \overset{def}= \bigoplus_{n \ge d} M_n$ is a finitely generated graded $S$-module ; the importance of this notion lies in the exercise, which shows that $M \sim M'$ (i.e. $M_{\ge d} \simeq M'_{\ge d}$ for some $d$) if and only if $\widetilde{M} \simeq \widetilde {M'}$.

The **box product** of $M$ and $N$ over $A$ is defined as the graded $S \boxtimes_A T$-module 
$$
M \boxtimes_A N \overset{def}= \bigoplus_{d \in \mathbb Z} M_d \otimes_A N_d
$$
where $(M \boxtimes_A N)_d \overset{def}= M_d \otimes_A N_d$ and $S \boxtimes_A T$ is defined by the same formulas. (I don't know if this standard notation, but I started writing it like this at some point and then forgot where it came from.) If $M$ and $N$ are quasi-finitely generated, so does $M \boxtimes_A N$, hence this suggests the definition
$$
\widetilde M \boxtimes_A \widetilde N \overset{def}= \widetilde{M \boxtimes_A N}.
$$
Question : Given $S,S',T,T'$ all as above ($A$ in degree $0$, f.g. in degree $1$), and morphisms $\varphi : \mathrm{Proj} S \to \mathrm{Proj} S'$, $\psi : \mathrm{Proj} T \to \mathrm{Proj}T'$, under what hypotheses do we have
$$
(\varphi \times \psi)^* \widetilde{M \boxtimes_A N} = \varphi^* \widetilde M \boxtimes \psi^* \widetilde N
$$
? I am mostly interested in the case where $\varphi,\psi$ are the $d$-uple embedding and $e$-uple embedding, since I was using this identity in the case where $A$ was a field to compute the Picard group without going through Weil  and Cartier divisors. In the case where $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are induced by graded ring homomorphisms, this is trivial, but in the more general cases I have made no progress. Note that the $d$-uple embedding is not given by a graded ring homomorphism since the pullback of the twisted sheaf $\mathcal O_Y(1)$ under such a morphism $\varphi : X \to Y$ is $\varphi^* \mathcal O_Y(1) = \mathcal O_X(1)$, which is not the case of the $d$-uple embedding : if $\varphi_d : \mathbb P^n \to \mathbb P^N$ is the embedding, $\varphi_d^* \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^N}(1) = \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}(d)$.